# Cannot undelete package components despite info saying you can

Tags: managed-package, package, beta-managed-package

I have deleted a Visualforce page in my managed package, however, this is now preventing me installing a new Beta version. I am on the page for Deleted Package Components. It says:

> This list contains components that were previously released and then deleted from this package. Some components deleted since the package was last uploaded as a Major Release may be undeleted.

There is an Action column but this is empty. How can I enable undeletion of package components?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One should be very careful removing components once a Managed Package has been release .The exact behavior you are facing has been documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm)

To get back the Undelete Action you will need to log a case from your partner portal and request the undelete link .